# How does Google mask the real URLs of links on search results pages?

Tags: javascript, url, href, google-search, web-inspector

The following I tested on the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox, and IE11, and the results were the same.

If you do a Google search and then mouse over a link on the search results page, the link shown in the bottom-left corner of the browser window is not the same as the actual `href` of the `a` element.
In all three browsers I tested this on, if you inspect the link in the element inspector though, you can easily see the real link (which is to `www.google.com`), and while the inspector is open, if you mouse over the link again, then you'll see the real URL link in the bottom-left corner of the browser window.

I have two questions regarding this behavior?

1. While perhaps a bit naive to ask, why does Google do this?
2. How does Google do this? Because I saw this behavior in Chrome, Firefox and IE11, I'm thinking that this is some JavaScript-controlled behavior (as opposed to some browser-controlled behavior), but I've never heard of this being possible in JavaScript. If it is possible in JavaScript, how do you do it?

Thank you.

Comment: When I mouse over the link with the inspector open, I still see the `www.google.com` URL in the corner of the browser.

Comment: +1 for Barmar. I see the same behavior.

Comment: Yes, you're both right. As I commented in PoByPobel's answer, it didn't occur to me at first that right-clicking on the link to open the inspect was causing the `onmousedown` event to occur, and the `rwt` function to be fired. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at the initial markup:

```
<a onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','3','AFQjCNF8xnW_qOvuZURbtcZUvB6zhKtRQw','35cXyZwuoZY8hBY1VfDr8Q','0CEAQFjAC','','',event)"
      href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_Do_You_Do_It%3F">
   <em>How Do You Do It</em>? - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
</a>
```

Initially the `href` attribute shows the "real" URL. But when you click on the link, the `rwt` function changes the attribute value to

```
http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEAQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FHow_Do_You_Do_It%253F&ei=8nSMUqXtLKfe4QSzwIDADQ&usg=AFQjCNF8xnW_qOvuZURbtcZUvB6zhKtRQw&sig2=35cXyZwuoZY8hBY1VfDr8Q&bvm=bv.56643336,d.bGE
```

To answer your question: they use the `onmousedown` attribute to change the link's `href` attribute when you click on it. [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20090958/2640170) points out why they do it.

Comment: Ahah, I didn't see that because I right-clicked on the link to use `Inspect element`, and that changed the link!

Comment: I did the same thing. But after I saw the `onmousedown` attribute I figured that Google had already changed the `href` value. So I tried a link I hadn't clicked on yet ;)

Comment: @PoByBolek, thanks a lot for this good answer. Like Barmar, I didn't consider the fact that when I right-click on the link to open the inspect, I am causing the mouse-down event to occur. Thanks for point that out. This almost all makes sense now. I still have one related follow-up question though, which I posted as a comment to Barmar's answer. Thanks.

Comment: If one disables javascript on the results page, the results use the tracking url (instead of the original) from the start

Answer (score 2):

The link in the results page points to a redirect page on the Google server. They do this so they can track which links people click on. This is more reliable than using Javascript, since it doesn't require users to have Javascript enabled.

You can see the eventual target of the link in the `url` parameter of the URL.

Comment: The use of tracking links doesn't require JavaScript, but you haven't explained how they make the eventual target appear in the status bar.

Comment: I haven't explained that because as far as I can tell it doesn't happen.

Comment: Well, it *does* happen. (And even if it didn't, I don't think you should post an answer that just silently ignores part of the question. At the very least, if a question is ill-posed and unanswerable, you should say so.)

Comment: I did, see my comment above. And my comment in PoByBolek's answer explains my misunderstanding.

Comment: See my first comment below the question.

Comment: @ruakh It is okay to put partial answers even if it doesn't solve the complete question -- see my question [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144452/is-it-okay-to-put-partial-answers)

Comment: @Barmar, thanks a lot for your explanation. I had one follow-up question to your answer though. You mentioned that Google does what they do for tracking purposes, and that it's a reliable technique since some users don't have JavaScript enabled, but if a user has JavaScript disabled, then the `href` of the link will never be changed, and they will never be directed to the Google server, right? Instead, they'll be taken directly to the actual URI, right? I just want to make sure that I'm not misunderstanding anything. Thanks.

Comment: @HartleySan In theory yes. But Google somehow notices that you have JavaScript disabled and (magically) sends you different markup, in which all `href`s contain the Google redirect URL.

Comment: They probably use `<noscript>` to detect that.

Comment: @aug: Of course it's fine to give a partial answer; all I said is that you should be explicit about it. This is especially the case when the reason you're not answering part of the question is that you think its premise is wrong. (In this case, it turns out that part of Barmar's answer was essentially wrong -- Google does use JavaScript to create the tracking URLs, and his answer clearly implies that it doesn't -- in a way that was intimately tied to the half of the question he didn't understand.)

Answer (score 1):

When the user clicks the `href`,
the `onmousedown` event handler gets executed 
before the default behaviour kicks in.
This time frame is used to change the href of the anchor tag.

Check out this simplified version of their code:

```html
<a 
  href="https://www.google.com/" 
  data-href='https://www.yahoo.com/' 
  onmousedown="this.href = this.dataset.href"
>Link</a>
```